# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):

Tags: load, caret

First time posting here.

Tried to search, couldn't find an exact example/result for my problem.

I'm trying to install and load caret, but keep getting the following error when trying to load ("library(caret)"):

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
> undefined exports: %++%, %ni%, Graph<-, Missing<-, Model<-, addvar<-, cancel<-, categorical<-, constrain<-, covariance<-, covfix<-, distribution<-, edgelabels<-, eventTime<-, exogenous<-, functional<-, heavytail<-, index<-, intercept<-, intervention<-, intfix<-, kill<-, labels<-, latent<-, nodecolor<-, nonlinear<-, offdiag<-, ordinal<-, parameter<-, parfix<-, randomslope<-, regfix<-, regression<-, revdiag<-, rmvar<-, timedep<-, transform<-, variance<-, Binary.lvm, By, CoefMat, CoefMat.multigroupfit, Col, Combine, Diff, Expand, GM2.lvm, GM3.lvm, Gamma.lvm, Graph, Grep, IV, Identical, Inverse, Missing, Model, NA2x, NR, OR, PD, Range.lvm, Ratio, Sequence.lvm, Specials, Weights, aalenExponential.lvm, addattr, addhook, addvar, adjMat, ancestors, as.sim, backdoor, baptize, beta.lvm, binary.lvm, binomial.lvm, binomial.rd, binomial.rr, blockdiag, bootstrap, cancel, categorical, children, chisq.lvm, click, clo
> In addition: Warning message:
> S3 methods ‘%++%.function’, ‘%++%.character’, ‘%++%.default’, ‘%++%.lvm’, ‘%++%.matrix’, ‘+.estimate’, ‘+.lvm’, ‘Graph<-.lvm’, ‘Graph<-.lvmfit’, ‘Model<-.lvm’, ‘Model<-.lvmfit’, ‘Model<-.multigroup’, ‘Model<-.multigroupfit’, ‘[.sim’, ‘addvar<-.lvm’, ‘cancel<-.lvm’, ‘constrain<-.default’, ‘constrain<-.multigroupfit’, ‘covariance<-.lvm’, ‘covfix<-.lvm’, ‘distribution<-.lvm’, ‘edgelabels<-.graphNEL’, ‘edgelabels<-.lvm’, ‘edgelabels<-.lvmfit’, ‘exogenous<-.lvm’, ‘functional<-.lvm’, ‘heavytail<-.lvm’, ‘index<-.lvm’, ‘index<-.lvmfit’, ‘intercept<-.lvm’, ‘intervention<-.lvm’, ‘kill<-.lvm’, ‘labels<-.default’, ‘latent<-.lvm’, ‘nodecolor<-.default’, ‘nodecolor<-.lvm’, ‘nonlinear<-.lvm’, ‘ordinal<-.lvm’, ‘parameter<-.lvm’, ‘parameter<-.lvmfit’, ‘parfix<-.lvm’, ‘randomslope<-.lvm’, ‘regfix<-.lvm’, ‘regression<-.lvm’, ‘rmvar<-.lvm’, ‘transform<-.lvm’, ‘variance<-.lvm’, ‘Graph.lvm’, ‘Graph.lvmfit’, ‘Model.default’, ‘Model.lvm’, ‘Model.lvmfit’, ‘Model.multigroup’, ‘Model.multigroupfit’, ‘Weights.def [... truncated]

Unfortunately I don't understand the error message, and what to do. This is what I've tried so far:

- Fresh install of R and Rstudio (newest versions)
- Updated all packages
- Reinstalled caret with "install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))"

Session info:

> R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252
> LC_CTYPE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252    LC_MONETARY=Norwegian
> Bokmål_Norway.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
> LC_TIME=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] lattice_0.20-45 forcats_0.5.1
> stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7     purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.1
> tidyr_1.1.4      [8] tibble_3.1.6    ggplot2_3.3.5   tidyverse_1.3.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] httr_1.4.2
> jsonlite_1.7.2     splines_4.1.2      foreach_1.5.1      modelr_0.1.8
> assertthat_0.2.1    [7] cellranger_1.1.0   globals_0.14.0
> pillar_1.6.4       backports_1.4.1    glue_1.5.1         digest_0.6.29
> [13] rvest_1.0.2        colorspace_2.0-2   Matrix_1.3-4
> plyr_1.8.6         timeDate_3043.102  pkgconfig_2.0.3    [19]
> broom_0.7.10       listenv_0.8.0      haven_2.4.3        scales_1.1.1
> gower_0.2.2        tzdb_0.2.0         [25] generics_0.1.1
> ellipsis_0.3.2     withr_2.4.3        nnet_7.3-16        cli_3.1.0
> survival_3.2-13    [31] magrittr_2.0.1     crayon_1.4.2
> readxl_1.3.1       fs_1.5.2           fansi_0.5.0        future_1.23.0
> [37] parallelly_1.30.0  nlme_3.1-153       MASS_7.3-54
> xml2_1.3.3         class_7.3-19       tools_4.1.2        [43]
> hms_1.1.1          lifecycle_1.0.1    munsell_0.5.0      reprex_2.0.1
> compiler_4.1.2     rlang_0.4.12       [49] grid_4.1.2
> iterators_1.0.13   rstudioapi_0.13    gtable_0.3.0
> codetools_0.2-18   DBI_1.1.1          [55] R6_2.5.1
> lubridate_1.8.0    future.apply_1.8.1 utf8_1.2.2         stringi_1.7.6
> parallel_4.1.2     [61] Rcpp_1.0.7         vctrs_0.3.8
> rpart_4.1-15       dbplyr_2.1.1       tidyselect_1.1.1

I get no error messages during the installation:

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
> installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
> Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/XXXX/XXXX
> XXXX/XXXX/R/win-library/4.1’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/caret_6.0-90.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 3590135 bytes (3.4 MB)
> downloaded 3.4 MB
>
> package ‘caret’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmSCIPo\downloaded_packages

Am I missing something basic here? Any help would be much appreciated!